# vmware player install hangs? vista 32bit

Tags: activex, installation, vmware, freeze

Hi
I am a noob trying to setup my computer so i can make a social networking website.
Sorry if its not kosher to ask here, but Hopefully one of you smart guys can help me.

I want to test some CMS (content management systems), firstly Elgg and then some others.
As far as ive read i can do this by using a virtual machine like VMware Player.

Now originally i wanted to try out Insoshi so i tried to use Cygwin and [GitBash](https://github.com/insoshi/insoshi) (also Putty tools) to download it (with no success). This involved me installing those programs and also trying to get an ssh environment variable working. So i gaveup on that (seeing that Elgg has more support anyhow i thought id try to try that). I uninstalled these programs, deleted leftover directories and deleted the added environment variable.

I also uninstalled DaemonTools (cos i thought it may be conflicting).
Im running Windows Vista 32bit and have always downloaded relevant installs for that system.

My problem is the VMware Player installer isn't doing anything. I launch it and it seems to hang straight away [see pic](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/6077/askfe.jpg)

Am i missing something here?
Vmware page also suggests a virtual appliance (for cloud stuff) which i dont know much about yet. And i think that appliance is installed via the player else an image loader like Daemon Tools. Do i need this appliance first?
Why is the player not installing?
Ive tried both 3.14 and 3.13 build with same result?
I have about 4 gig of space left on my hd and have 3gig of ram.
I have looked at the programs installed on my computer and cant seem to find anything else that might conflict (but i am a n00b) and i also tried pausing my kapersky pure protection. Any help is severely appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall there were a couple of conflicts with vmware

A quick look through the vmware forums I see:

- visualsvn
- virtualPC (no surprise)
- nvidia 270.18 beta driver
- avg

I also remember there being talk on the forums about a specific executable name which caused issues, but Im struggling to remember what it was.

Comment: i dont run avg, just kaspersy pure and tried disabling that. have never used the other two either. however, my video card is (on a laptop) nVidia Geforce 8600GM using the latest driver for that (266.58) which i updated yesterday. I have had a lot of nvidia driver issues before (this one seems to be running ok however for now). But it looks like this may well be the conflictor. This laptop is the only computer suitable in the house. So if this is the issue i may have to wait till i get a new computer running with a better video card.

Comment: Ive been running 266.58 with vmware for a while now, so it isnt that. I do remember something, and I dont remember what it was, but there was an exe name that caused issues with the installer..

Comment: Only other thought would be to redownload the installer, in case its not quite right, did you check the crc check of it?

Comment: @ bugfinder
i am not educated with crc check but just downloaded it and ran it on the installer which returned the string CDCE2DE5
what do i do with that? Also created a dump file of process, but am reading how to examine that still. Also overlooked magic iso maker and uninstalled that which didnt fix the vmware install problem (but without a restart).

Comment: On the page on VMwares site you download the player form it has md5 and sha1sum, http://www.vmware.com/download/md5.html and http://www.vmware.com/download/cryptographichashes.html are linked at the bottom.  Have you had Vmware server/workstation installed on this PC before if so run the setup with /c

Comment: @ bugfinder thanks, FCIV made it easy for me (n00b)
the MD5sum matched (even after i renamed the file for command FCIV)
i was hoping it wouldnt, so the file is consistent, but its still not working, im going to try another restart

Comment: Before you restart the install, my advice, look through all the services for things that arent native with vista, and then disable them all (making notes as to what), and reboot, as you login, hold down shift as you hit "Ok" so that it doesnt run startup apps, that way you're running a basic windows without any extras, now do the install.

Comment: @bugfinder wwwwow! thankyou! I went to go do what you suggested above and i found that the extended tab in services would not open due to an active x error. this registry fix fixed it [link] http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprosecurity/thread/90c3202c-448b-42b7-acf7-dab8dba7b000 some users suggested it was due to an adobe update my brother just installed Air so maybe but another said that this registry entry disabled the windows sidebar which i know i did yonks ago so it seems the installer was loading an active x script or whatever and it was being blocked by this thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

1. start regedit.exe
2. Browse to the following sub-key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\
3. You should see keys named 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. In my case I had a folder named "L" before the 0.
4. Remove the key with "L" (actually it is  "└", unicode #2514)

P.S. This is due to Microsoft screws up the registry Internet Zone settings in the registry. With the "└" key, it cause Javascript not to be called from an application.

Got it from **[here](http://myseq.blogspot.in/2011/10/installationuninstallation-of-vmware.html)**.